# calculate the limit of a function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate the limite of this function when $x\to\infty$.

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}}\right)^x\exp(-2c\sqrt{x})$, where $c$ is a constant.

Numerically, I plot a graphic of this function, and I think the answer is 1. But theoretically, I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Why without L’Hôpital? Is it curiosity? Or is it a requirement in your course?

Comment: Because l'hôpital does not work, at least I did not succeed :(

Comment: sorry for the deleted comments, I misread the function. Since $x$ is near $+\infty$ you can say $\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}}>0$ so you can use $ln$.

Comment: $(\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}})^x = e^{xln(\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}})}$ after simplification you study the expression depending on the sign of $c$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you should find : 
$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f_c(x) = 1$ if $c = 0$,
$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f_c(x) = 0$ if $c > 0$, and
$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f_c(x) = +\infty$ if $c < 0$

Comment: @Conan There is no dependence on $c$.  The limit is $1$.

Comment: @Mark Viola Thanks, misread the first factor then the second. Wasn't rigourous.

Comment: @YUxiWang Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the  best answer I can.

Answer (score 6):

Using $\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ we find

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}}\right)^x e^{-2c\sqrt x}&=e^{x\log\left(\frac{1+c/\sqrt{x}}{1-c/\sqrt{x}}\right)}e^{-2c\sqrt x}\\\\
&=\exp\left({2cx^{1/2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c^{2n}}{(2n+1)x^{n}}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Letting $x\to \infty$, we find

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{c+\sqrt{x}}{-c+\sqrt{x}}\right)^x e^{-2c\sqrt x}=1 $$

Comment: Thankyou! Your answer is so clear.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go beyond the limit, considering

$$y= \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+c}{\sqrt{x}-c}\right)^x \,e^{-2 c \sqrt{x}}$$ take logarithms
$$\log(y)=x \log\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+c}{\sqrt{x}-c}\right)-2 c \sqrt{x}=x \log \left(1+\frac{2 c}{\sqrt{x}-c}\right)-2 c \sqrt{x}$$ Now use the series expansion of $\log(1+\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon=\frac{2 c}{\sqrt{x}-c}$ and continue with long division to obtain
$$\log(y)=\frac{2 c^3}{3 \sqrt{x}}\Bigg[1+\frac{3 c^2}{5 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \Bigg]$$ that is to say
$$y \sim \exp\Bigg[\frac{2 c^3}{3 \sqrt{x}} \Bigg]$$